# pass var values from one swf to another swf who is loaded inside the firts one in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

im using this method to load an SWF inside another SWF:
(this code is inside main.swf)

```
function loadImage(url:String):void {
imageLoader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, imageLoading);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
}
loadImage("test1.swf");

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
MyMovieClip.addChild(imageLoader); 
}
```

The think is the test1.swf needs a value who is in the loader swf (main.swf), how can i pass the value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class for the loaded SWF ( test1.swf ) which you can assign with the Document class.

In this class create a setter for the values you need to pass to the loaded SWF.

```
   //Here the choice of Array is arbitrary & depends on what values
   //you need to pass to the SWF...
   private var _params:Array;
   public function set params( value:Array ):void
   {
      _params = value;
   }
```

Then in your Main class, you can do the following:

```
  //Assuming you'd like to pass a number of values...
  function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {

      var content:MovieClip = imageLoader.content as CustomClass;
      content.params = [ value1 , value2... valueN];
      MyMovieClip.addChild(content);
  }
```

Comment: Hi PatrickS, when you have a moment, could you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933387/how-to-pass-a-string-from-a-swf-into-another-swf

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the content of the loader to do this. In your imageLoaded function do this.

```
( e.target.content as Object ).someParam = "whatever";
```

There are a number of security restrictions to consider, (This is called cross scripting), but if you are loading two swfs from the same domain, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: How is this exactly written btw? By that I mean how does it fit into the exact loader function she wrote? I'm having the same problem :(