# What is the best practice for communicating between a parent and child SWF in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Consider you have A.swf generated by compiling A.fla. A.fla's document root class is `AStage()`. Now consider B.swf and it's B.fla. If B.fla loads A.swf. Can it cast A.swf's stage object to `AStage()`?

If this is not possible, what is the recommended approach for communicating with child SWFs?

Comment: If AStage is visible by B.fla(AStage gets compiled in B.swf, a simple import and variable declaration, without instantiation should do) you should be able to cast. If not, you need to use A.swf's applicationDomain and getDefinition to get a definition of AStage as a Class, after that you should be able to cast A.swf to AStage.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would consider it 'best practice' to use an interface to cast to rather than your SWF's document class itself. Be careful of using the word stage as a Flash application has only one stage regardless of how many SWF's it loads.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question here: 
[pass var values from one swf to another swf who is loaded inside the firts one in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576719/pass-var-values-from-one-swf-to-another-swf-who-is-loaded-inside-the-firts-one-in/4577257#4577257)

Apart from this , it is generally possible for a parent and a child to belong to the same class, consider Sprites for instance.